# lines are cut when the price crosses them

Tags: pine-script, trading

help me.
I need that when the price crosses the drawn lines, they are cut.
as shown in the images below.

```
    //@version=4
var maxBarsBack = 10
study("Zones Supply and Demand", shorttitle="SD & RSI",overlay=true, max_bars_back=maxBarsBack)
ColorZDem=input(color.new(color.lime, 100), title="Color Zona Demanda")
ColorZSuply=input(color.new(color.red, 100), title="Color Zona Oferta")

// define a basing and explosive candles
basing_candle = ((abs(close - open)/abs(high - low)) < 0.51)
explosive_candle = (abs(close-open) / abs(high - low)) >= 0.51 and tr>tr[1] 

/// functions
bc_r = basing_candle and close < open
ex_g = explosive_candle and close > open
bc_rz = basing_candle and close > open
ex_gz = explosive_candle and close < open


// zone
demandzone = (bc_r[1] and ex_g and low>=low[1] and close>open[1]) 
supplyzone = (bc_rz[1] and ex_gz and high<=high[1] and close<open[1]) 


line l1 = na
line l2 = na

dz = if demandzone and barstate.isconfirmed
    l1 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1] ,y1=low[1], x2=bar_index, y2= low[1], style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right, color=ColorZDem, width=1)

sz = if supplyzone and barstate.isconfirmed
    l2 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1] ,y1=high[1], x2=bar_index, y2= high[1], style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right, color=ColorZSuply, width=1)



for i = 1 to maxBarsBack
    a=line.get_y1(l1[i])
    line.set_color(id=l1[i], color=cross(a,close[1])?color.new(color.lime,100):color.new(color.lime,0))
    //line.set_x2(id=l1[i], x=b)
    
    
        // We have identified a bar where a line was created.
//        line.delete(l1[i])

//    if not na(l2[i]) and close > high[i]
//        // We have identified a bar where a line was created.
//        line.delete(l2[i])
```

I want the lines to be cut when the price crosses them, as in this image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH09x.jpg)

Comment: HELP!!!HELP!!!HELP!!!HELP!!!HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get on your way. We maintain a distinct array of lines for the demand and supply lines. The lines are drawn without an extension, so on each bar we loop across the arrays of lines and extend the lines manually using `line.set_x2(_currentLine, bar_index)`.

When a line is crossed by the `close`, we delete the line id from the array but keep the line itself in place so that it continues to show.

Provision has to be made for cases where the line is never crossed. If that happens after `i_maxLineLength` bars, the line is deleted.

A maximum of 500 lines can be displayed on the chart (see `max_lines_count = 500` in the `study()` call).

```
//@version=4
var maxBarsBack = 10
study("Zones Supply and Demand", shorttitle="SD & RSI",overlay=true, max_lines_count = 500)
ColorZDem=input(color.new(color.lime, 0), title="Color Zona Demanda")
ColorZSuply=input(color.new(color.red, 0), title="Color Zona Oferta")
int i_maxLineLength = input(400, "Maximum line length in bars", minval = 2)

// define a basing and explosive candles
basing_candle = ((abs(close - open)/abs(high - low)) < 0.51)
explosive_candle = (abs(close-open) / abs(high - low)) >= 0.51 and tr>tr[1] 

/// functions
bc_r = basing_candle and close < open
ex_g = explosive_candle and close > open
bc_rz = basing_candle and close > open
ex_gz = explosive_candle and close < open


// zone
demandzone = (bc_r[1] and ex_g and low>=low[1] and close>open[1]) 
supplyzone = (bc_rz[1] and ex_gz and high<=high[1] and close<open[1]) 

var line[] demandLines = array.new_line(0)
var line[] supplyLines = array.new_line(0)

if demandzone and barstate.isconfirmed
    array.push(demandLines, line.new(x1 = bar_index[1], y1=low[1], x2=bar_index, y2= low[1], style=line.style_solid, color=ColorZDem))
else if supplyzone and barstate.isconfirmed
    array.push(supplyLines, line.new(x1 = bar_index[1], y1=high[1], x2=bar_index, y2= high[1], style=line.style_solid, color=ColorZSuply))

f_processLines(_arrayOfLines) =>
    int _qtyOfLines = array.size(_arrayOfLines)
    if _qtyOfLines > 0
        for _i = _qtyOfLines - 1 to 0
            line  _currentLine = array.get(_arrayOfLines, _i)
            float _lineLevel   = line.get_price(_currentLine, bar_index)
            bool  _lineCrossed = sign(close[1] - _lineLevel) != sign(close - _lineLevel)
            line.set_x2(_currentLine, bar_index)
            if _lineCrossed or bar_index - line.get_x1(_currentLine) > i_maxLineLength
                array.remove(_arrayOfLines, _i)

f_processLines(demandLines)
f_processLines(supplyLines)

// Debugging.
plotchar(demandzone, "demandzone", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(supplyzone, "supplyzone", "▼", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]